# Execute two distinct projects with code blocks

Tags: c++, ide, codeblocks

I have an issue with code blocks.

I have two distinct projects, one for the server and the other for the client. I would execute both of them at the same time for debugging. How can I do that ?

I have been trying settings -> environement -> [ ]"Allow only one running instance" and [ ]"Use an already running instance" but it doesn't work.

I wanna run my server and 3 clients at the same time in debug mode with code block.

I'm using code blocks 10.05 on ubuntu 12.04

Comment: What doesn't work? Say what you want to happen and what is actually happening.

Comment: I can't be clearer. I can run only 1 instance of every project, and only 1 project. I wanna run my server and 3 clients at the same time in debug mode with code blocks.

Comment: For others coming to this page, it looks like there is a misunderstanding: unchecking the "Allow only one running instance" is not concerned with instances of *projects*, it's instances of the Code::Blocks application *itself*. If you uncheck the box you'll be able to launch multiple Code::Blocks application windows, it does not have any effect on launching a project multiple times, or launching multiple projects concurrently.

Answer (score 3):

if this not working

> settings -> environement -> [ ]"Allow only one running instance" and [ ]"Use an already running instance" but it doesn't work.

it also will not work

> codeblocks --multiple-instance &

then use this command

```
$ codeblocks --multiple-instance --no-ipc &
```

but after that, you don't have connection with some server of C::B - as result you can't save any changes in env settings, like for example a new compiler etc.

Answer (score 2):

If I uncheck the environment options you mentioned I can run as many
C::B instances as I like. This is with C::B 13.12, but 10.5 should be the same.
If it is not working for you for some reason then you should be able to
force it by running in a terminal:

```
codeblocks --multiple-instance &
```

as many times as required.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Windows7, try to delete the entire registry entry with regedit:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CodeBlocks.cbp\shell\open\ddeexec
```

This may also work for some version of MS Office Excel.